# Is using number+letter a safe separator for text?

Tags: text-editing

Considering you have to delimit your text without using special characters, can using [0-9][a-z] (0e, 0f, etc.) be considered safe?

In other words, in computer languages and in general text,
is it possible to (except for some cases of hash values etc.)
encounter for example '0e' in text/code?

Purpose is to use this variant of letter combination to separate fields.

e.g.: Field1 *0e* Field2 *0e* Field3

(Entries are always a single line consisting of multiple fields)

Comment: Everything is possible. If you really are limited to numbers and letters (and I assume spaces) consider a long ambiguous word between spaces where _ is a space, such as: `_1111111SeparatorOfFields1111111_` The longer your word is, the less likely it is that it comes up as an actual field. Alternatively, consider something like 10 spaces, but that may actually be in your text more often than the earlier option.

Comment: good idea with the spaces (using 5 or so), I will elaborate on that option. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Some languages (FORTRAN) don't consider spaces at all (except at the start of the line). Others (Lisp, FORTH) allow literally anything (excluding spaces) in names. What strange junk I'll want to show in my text (including examples of text delimited by whatever scheme you'd propose) is anybody's guess...  There *can't* be "safe sequences" that aren't sanctioned by the format at hand. And there it will probably be abusing some existing structure (comments, newlines, spaces at start/end of line).

Comment: Agree that it always depends on situation, altough I am focusing on one line entries, which means no indentation spaces etc.

Comment: Safe separator is possible if you allow some encoding. E.g. if you store fields so each `X` is replaced (encoded) by `XX` then your separator can be `OXO`. Now each occurrence of `OXO` is the separator for sure. Other `X`s must appear in pairs. Single `X` that doesn't belong to a separator is invalid. After you read the fields you need to decode: replace each `XX` with `X`. This example may not be optimal. Another way is to separate with sole `X`, encode `X` as `ZX` and encode `Z` as `ZZ`. This is similar to what you need to do to pass `"` or `\ ` in a double-quoted string in a shell.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski this is in my opinion the answer to this question. Why not post an answer?

Comment: @LPChip Maybe I'm being too literal but the answer to "is using number+letter a safe separator for text?" is "no" and this answer has already been given. The answer to "is it possible to encounter for example '0e' in text/code?" is "yes" and it has been given as well. My comment answers none of these. It would be an answer to "how to separate fields safely?" but this is not the OP's question.

Comment: I feel your answer is a bit extreme, I would like to use what's already existing, not a double-standard this is encoded as this and this as that. Same library of characters and one "playground" is preferred.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I agree with you, but then there is the famous X-Y problem, and this is such case. So stating that its a no, and then giving this alternative makes it from a good answer to a great answer.

Comment: @user12938074 what he is suggesting is using an escape character. If you look at how MSDos did it, which was very limited by itself, they had an escape character, and in order to use that escape character in any field, it was escaped by itself. This technique is very valid even to todays standards. You basically first search/replace the field for your escape character and replace it with twice the escape character, then store it, and separate it with a separator that has a single escape character. Once you retrieve the value, you simply merge the double to a single. Perfect solution.

Comment: @LPChip Well, in such case the question should be improved first and ask for X, not Y. This is how I feel about it. I officially allow anyone to take my comment and write an answer based on it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'll write up the answer then, because it is a really good answer. ;) It should not be burried in the comments.

Comment: @user12938074 Some standards (less or more formal) exist: [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values). And [this convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values#Conventions_for_lossless_conversion_to_TSV) is an example of what I was talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Kamil, thanks to which I started focusing on using simple comma scenario for field separation

Answer (score 1):

Originally suggested by Kamil Maciorowski in the comments above, this answer is based upon his feedback. I'll make this a Community wiki so I don't earn rep for it.

> Is using number+letter a safe separator for text?

The answer is no. The shorter a combination of letters and numbers is, the higher the chance this can be the content of one of the cells you want to split.

That said, Kamil Maciorowski, came up with a good alternative.

Your goal is obviously finding a good way to store more than one piece of information in a table, where you only have letters, numbers and spaces available.

It is common practice to work with escape characters. You can simply make this if you double-escape the escape character whenever it occurs in your field.

Lets say you want to create a special character: `1`, For every field you store in your dataset, you would replace all occurrences of `1` with `11`. Now, `1` can be used as special character, because it will never appear as just a 1.

So to separate fields, you could simply use `_1_` (the _ is a space, but was written as _ for visibility.)

Lets say, you have the following dataset that you want to store, `1,12,123`
You would replace all 1's with 11, and the , which is invalid as separator, with proper separators, aka `_1_`, your dataset would look like this: `11 1 112 1 1123`

In order to use this data again, first you split the text to an array, where `_1_` is your separator, then you cycle through all entries in the array and change 11 to 1, turning the array into `1,12,123`.

Comment: That is an interesting answer, altough I am not sure if I understand it well. What I got to from ideas from you guys is using a comma 'field1, field2, ..' as separator, while using \, to use comma in the fields

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not be considered save.
Just use your own question as an example. You already have the sequence '0e' four times in there.
It's never save or a good idea to use what could be content of a field to delimit the fields.
And by using multiple characters you can make it more unlikely to conflict with field content but you might not be sure what you will store in there in the future.

Comment: Well, but then no character could be used as separator, as it would be mentioned somewhere (tab, some special symbol or anything else). And the only safe delimiter would be newline